# What does it line mean in bash?

Tags: bash, perl, unicode

`spkgender=$(perl -ane ' s/.*gender\:\W*(.).*/lc($1)/ei && print; ' <$rdm)`

It is regex and it extracts `M` from 'Gender: Male', but it doesn't work for unicode.

How to make it work with unicode?

It doesn't work for 'Gender: Мужской' - looks like `\W` "eats" all unicode symbols.

Comment: You say it doesn't work with Unicode, there are various Unicode encodings which one is your input file in

Comment: How do I check it in ubuntu?

Comment: `file input file name`

Comment: What is this command?

Comment: the `file` command gives info on a file, for text files it includes the encoding

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and show us the (anonymized) input for which it works, and the input for which it fails?

Comment: This is just a Perl question; the fact that you are running `perl` from `bash` isn't really relevant.

Comment: Can you tell me what perl is doing and how to fix unicode?

Comment: You will need to tell Perl that its input is supposed to be UTF-8. `perl -C -ane ...` See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for further information.

Comment: Thanks. It works!

Answer (score -1):

Use `/u` regex modifier. Source: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

```
spkgender=$(perl -ane ' s/.*gender\:\W*(.).*/lc($1)/uei && print; ' <$rdm)
```

Alternately, use the official POSIX character class. instead of `\W` use `[[:blank:]]`. As far as I know it supports Unicode.

Also, please make sure you are using Unicode correctly in general. Reference: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html

> When the string has come from an external source marked as Unicode
>   The -C command line option can specify that certain inputs to the program are Unicode, and the values of this can be read by your Perl code, see ${^UNICODE} in perlvar.

Comment: That didn't work for me @Corion's suggestion in the comments on the question did